# Docker haproxy issue with web path

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose, haproxy

I am trying to get haproxy to connect to the webserver using `localhost/path`

My current setup is as folows:

```
HAproxy_test
│   docker-compose.yml
│
├───haproxy
│       Dockerfile
│       haproxy.cfg
│
└───website
        index.php
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'

services:

  website1:
    image: php:apache
    hostname: website_1
    volumes: 
      - ./website:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  haproxy:
    build: ./haproxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - website1
```

**haproxy/Dockerfile:**

```
FROM haproxy

COPY haproxy.cfg /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

**haproxy/haproxy.cfg:**

```
global
    maxconn 5000

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout client 5s
    timeout server 5s

frontend http_in
    bind *:80

    acl has_web1 path_beg -i /web1 
    use_backend http_out if has_web1

    default_backend http_out

backend http_out
    server web1 website1:80 check
```

Using `docker-compose up --build` everything comes up fine. 
If type in `localhost` or `localhost:8080` it takes me to the website and everything is great BUT if i try `localhost/web1` I get a 404 Not Found

[image]

HOWEVER, if I change my dockder-compose.yml for example to use `image: dockercloud/hello-world` instead of `image: php:apache` the `localhost/web1` works just fine

[image]

Am I missing some configuration in apache that is pressent in the dockercloud/hello-world image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like your redirect rule in NGINX is working, but the apache server is receiving a request for the path WWWROOT/web1, so Apache is looking for the file or directory at path WWWROOT/web1 which is non-existent, thus giving a 404. You could test by adding the sub directory web1 with basic index.html, and check if that gets served.